# Generate random numbers with 3 to 7 digits in R

Tags: r, random, sample

How can I generate random numbers of varying length, say between 3 to 7 digits with equal probability.

At the end I would like the code to come up with a 3 to 7 digit number (with equal probability) consisting of random numbers between 0 and 9.

I came up with this solution but feel that it is overly complicated because of the obligatory generation of a data frame.

```
options(scipen=999)
t <- as.data.frame(c(1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000))
round(runif(1, 0,1) * sample_n(t,1, replace = TRUE),0)
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I think you would want to clarify whether the statement on "equal probability" refers to whether the uniform distribution is over all possible numbers (that is, it is more likely to pick a 7-digit number because they are the largest class of numbers here) or whether you want the chance of picking 3,4,5,6 or 7 digits in the first place to be equally probable.

Comment: The second is the case. The chance of picking either digit length in the first place should be equally probable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a vectorized approach, and sample from the allowed range of exponents directly in the exponent:

```
pick.nums <- function(n){floor(10^(sample(3:7,n,replace = TRUE))*runif(n))}
```

For example,

```
> set.seed(123)
> pick.nums(5)
[1]     455  528105   89241 5514350 4566147
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information you provided, I came up with another solution that might be closer to what you want. In the end, it consists of these steps:

- randomly pick a number `len` from [3, 7] determining the length of the output
- randomly pick `len` numbers from [0, 9]
- concatenate those numbers

Code to do that:

```
(len <- runif(1, 3, 7) %/% 1)
(s <- runif(len, 0, 9) %/% 1)
cat(s, sep = "")
```

---

I previously provided this answer; it does not meet the requirements though, as became clear after OP provided further details.

Doesn't that boil down to generating a random number between 100 and 9999999?
If so, does this do what you want?

```
runif(5, 100, 9999999) %/% 1
```

You could probably also use round, but you'd always have to round down.

Output:

```
[1] 4531543 9411580 2195906 3510185 1129009
```

Comment: Almost. In this case, I think the "000" is also considered a valid 3-digit number (and also any one- and two-digit number with trailing zeros).

Comment: The problem here is that, as Brandmeier stated above, that the probability of getting 7 digit numbers is higher than of getting 3 digit numbers. However, I would like them to be equal.

Comment: Ah, I see, well then my approach is not what you want. Shame, that!